# plot line graph in Chartjs 2 when number of data in yaxis is not eqaul to number of data in xaxis

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs-2

I have two arrays for ploting the graph. Let me tell with an example.

```
yAxis = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
xAxis = [10:10, 10:20, 10:30, 10:40, 10:50, 11:00]
```

In this case, graph will plot correctly.
Then after clicking some button 'A' in my page, the xAxis is modified like,

```
xAxis = [10:10, 10:15, 10:20, 10:25, 10:30, 10:35, 10:40, 10:45, 10:50, 10:55, 11:00]
```

but my yAxis will always be the same as,

```
yAxis = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In this case, the graph will plot till '10:35' in xAxis
Then after clicking some button 'B' in my page, the xAxis is modified like,

```
xAxis = [10:10, 10:40, 11:00]
```

but my yAxis will always be the same as,

```
yAxis = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In this case, the graph will plot till '6' in yAxis

Is their any way to fix this issue?
I was tring to implement in reactjs application with react-chartjs-2

***Or is their any way to split the time in xAxis if start time, end time and required,intervals is passed to graph ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by adding the time which should come in between and changing all the existing lines ploted in the graph and added snapGap:true.